# Yii2 full width layout in index.php

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, yii2

What is the best practice to make different layouts for pages in Yii2?
The problem I am facing is that Yii2 layout/main.php code looks like

```
<div class="container">
   <?= $content ?>
</div>
```

Yii2 uses Bootstrap and I need to make full width image only in site/index.php. 
Basically in the index.php I need to wrap

```
<?= $this->render('_search') ?>
```

into **.container-fluid** class.

How can I replace **.container** class to **.container-fluid** class only for index.php page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a new layout, e.g. `layout-fluid.php`, and in controller do

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $this->layout = 'layout-fluid';
    return $this->render('index');
}
```

If fluid container is the only change you need, you can do this instead: in index view file add

```
$this->params['fluid'] = true;
```

And in layout file change the desired container to

```
<div class="container<?= $this->params['fluid'] ? '-fluid' : '' ?>">
```

[`params`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-view.html#$params-detail) array is a good place to propagate information within view.

Comment: Thank you. Adding $this->layout = 'layout-fluid'; to controller did the trick. Params array is clear when it is used in the view like index.php but what if I need to change it in layout file(main.php) only for index.php page? The one thing that bothers me is that I copied main.php to layout-fluid.php and the only difference between them is class name. But other code like Menu and footer is the same in both files. Is it good or bad practice?

Comment: Sure, you don't need extra layout if it is the only difference. For basic/advanced Yii projects index page view file is `views/site/index.php`, and I guess it is your index.php page, right?

Comment: Yes, views/site/index.php is the file I need to change.

Comment: I attempted your $this->params['fluid'] = true method and was unsuccessful. Can params be changed in the controller or is it possible the params are cached?

Comment: @JairusMartin I guess you can but make sure that you're doing this before $this->render is called. I don't do much Yii for now so if the problem persists for you I would suggest to ask a new question with http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that reflects your case.

Answer (score 2):

If you need just change wrapper class only for site/index, in main.php you can do it like this:

```
<div class="container<?=($this->context->id=='site' && $this->context->action->id=='index')?'-fluid':'';?>">
   <?= $content ?>
</div>
```